# how to get Global IP address?

Tags: networking, ip

When my PC is connected to Network, I will be getting couple of IP address.

1.) Modem Private IP address (will be like 192.168.1.3)
2.) ISP address (by searching "My ip address" in google it gives me my global IP address)

My roommate who is connected to same modem is able to ping my global IP address but not other person who is connected to different network, why??

Is there anyway that in ISP they block ICMP Packets?? So that no one be able to ping other machine ?? or do they use different routing instances for different sectors??

If we want a global IP address for my PC so that anyone can login/ping what should I enable??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your router/modem gets a dynamic IP from ISP whenever you connect it to Internet. This address as name says is changing. If you want a constant public IP from ISP, you must request ISP for the same. This comes at a very high cost and not recommended unless you are serving a high revenue generating data on that machine.